# borderColor if null value

Tags: php, html-table

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2testing)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><center>$i</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['matricNo'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><center>" . $row['LC'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Code'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Subject'] . "</td>";
  if(!empty($row['Assignment1'])) {
    echo "<td><center><font color='red'>" . $row['Assignment1'] . "</td>"; 
  }
  echo "<td><center>" . $row['Quiz'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><center>" . $row['Participation'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><center>" . $row['Attendance'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><center>" . $row['Exam'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

This is my simple code.
How to make my column red if assigment1 is null
and assigment1 is not null to blue

Comment: can you please tell me that the problem u are facing..!!

Answer (score 0):

`style="background-color:red;"` and `background-color:blue;` is possibly what you are looking for. You did not specify how the columns should be painted so you might have to adjust this.

Just insert this to your columns or rows you want to apply the color:

e.g. for a row (guess this is your header):

```
echo "<td style="background-color:red;"><center><font color='blue'>" . $row['Assignment1'] . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in the first echo

`echo "<tr style='background-color:" . (($row['Assignment1'] === NULL) ? "red" : "blue") . "'>";`

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with below code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2testing))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>$i</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['matricNo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['LC'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Subject'] . "</td>";
if(!empty($row['Assignment1']))
{
echo "<td><center><font color='blue'>" . $row['Assignment1'] . "</td>"; 
  }
else
{
echo "<td><center><font color='red'>" . $row['Assignment1'] . "</td>"; 
}
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Quiz'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Participation'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Attendance'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Exam'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Nice, simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query2testing))
  {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>$i</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['matricNo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['LC'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Subject'] . "</td>";
  if(!empty($row['Assignment1']))
  {
echo "<td><center><font color='blue'>" . $row['Assignment1'] . "</td>"; 
  }
else {
echo "<td><center><font color='red'>" . $row['Assignment1'] . "</td>"; 
}
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Quiz'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Participation'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Attendance'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Exam'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Three** (3) things:

Let's convert your ***MySQL*** to ***MySQLi***. Just put ***else*** on to your `if(empty($row['Assignment1']))`. **AND** ***Border Color*** is what you want to change color, right?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","database");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

$i=1;

$query2testing=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM yourTable");

echo "<table>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2testing))
  {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>$i</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['matricNo'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['LC'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Subject'] . "</td>";
if(empty($row['Assignment1']))
{
echo "<td style='border: 1px solid red;'><center>" .$row['Assignment1'] . "</td>";  /* YOU WANT THE BORDER TO CHANGE COLOR, RIGHT? */
}
else {
echo "<td style='border: 1px solid blue;'><center>" .$row['Assignment1']."</td>"; /* YOU WANT THE BORDER TO CHANGE COLOR, RIGHT? */
}

echo "<td><center>" . $row['Quiz'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Participation'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Attendance'] . "</td>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['Exam'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  $i++;
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```